# Why there's a sin and cos here? Shouldn't the obvious guess be $Ae^{-x}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image shows the solution for the differential equation y double prime minus 4 y prime plus 5 y equal to e powered to the minus x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDP8G.png)

I solved this $y'' - 4y' + 5y = e^{-x}$ equation with the guess of:

$Ae^{-x}$, such that A ended up being $A = 1/2$;

The solution given by math calculator websites was the one of the image —

$$y(x)=(C_1 \sin(x)+C_2 \cos(x))e^{2x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{10},$$

but I can't understand how could I ever get to that solution on my own.
Can someone explain the logic to me?

Comment: That is because the characteristic equation has complex roots, so the associated homogeneous equation has solutions involving $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: To use classroom terminology, you found the *particular* solution of the differential equation, but not the *homogeneous* solution (solution to $y''-4y'+5y = 0$). The general solution to a linear ODE is the sum of the particular and homogeneous solutions.

Comment: You miscalculated the value of $A$ – it should be $\dfrac1{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

The auxiliary equation of the given ODE is,

$m^2-4m+5 = 0 \Rightarrow (m-2)^2 +1 = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{m = 2 \pm i}$

So the solution (complementary function) will be,

$$y_{CF}(x) = k_1 e^{(2 + i)x} + k_2 e^{(2 - i)x} =e^{2x}(k_1 e^{ix} + k_2 e^{-ix}) \equiv \boxed{e^{2x}(C_1 \sin x + C_2\cos x)}$$

Now you have to add this with the particular solution to get the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

okay lets solve it, first:
$$y''-4y'+5y=0$$
lets make an educated guess that the solutions will be of the form:
$$y=Ae^{\lambda x}$$
now sub in:
$$Ae^{\lambda x}(\lambda^2-4\lambda+5)=0$$
solving for $\lambda$ the non-trivial solutions are going to be in the quadratic:
$$\lambda^2-4\lambda+5=0$$
$$\lambda=2\pm i$$
now we add these two solutions together:
$$y=Ae^{(2+i)x}+Be^{(2-i)x}=e^{2x}(Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix})$$
now notice that this will just form sines and cosines so lets redefine our constants and we arrive at:
$$y=e^{2x}\left(C_1\sin x+C_2 \cos x\right)$$
This part forms the "complementary function" so now you just need to find the particular solution. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let us pretend that we know nothing about the linear ODE with constant coefficients nor complex exponentials.

We will try by factoring $y$ and get some simplification.

$$y=zh,\\y'=z'h+zh',\\y''=z''h+2z'h'+zh''.$$

We plug this in the ODE:

$$z''h+2z'(h'-2h)+z(h''-4h'+5h)=e^{-x}$$ and let the coefficient of $z'$ vanish.

From $h'-2h=0$, which is separable,

$$\frac{h'}h=(\log(h))'=2$$ and $h=e^{2x}$ is a solution.

Plugged in the ODE gain,

$$z''e^{2x}+ze^{2x}=e^{-x}$$ or

$$z''+z=e^{-3x}.$$

Now if we try a solution of the form $e^{-3x}$ by educated guess, we get that

$$z''+z=10\,e^{-3x}$$ and it suffices to correct with a suitable factor.

So, using linearity of the derivative, we can move the RHS as

$$z''-\frac9{10}e^{-3x}+z-\frac1{10}e^{-3x}=0$$ or

$$\left(z-\frac1{10}e^{-3x}\right)''+\left(z-\frac1{10}e^{-3x}\right)=0$$

which is of the form $$w''+w=0.$$ We make it integrable by multiplying by $2w'$:

$$2w'w''+2ww'=(w'^2+w^2)'=0$$ and for some (positive) constant $a^2$,

$$w'^2=a^2-w^2$$ then

$$\frac{w'}{\sqrt{a^2-w^2}}=\pm1.$$

After integration,

$$\arccos\frac wa=\pm t+c$$

or

$$w=a\cos(\pm t+c)=c_c\cos t+c_s\sin t.$$

Finally,

$$y=ze^{2x}=\left(w+\frac{e^{-3x}}{10}\right)e^{2x}=\left(c_c\cos t+c_s\sin t+\frac{e^{-3x}}{10}\right)e^{2x}
\\=\left(c_c\cos t+c_s\sin t\right)e^{2x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{10}$$ as claimed.